# Image Upload and File Attachment in TinyMCE for ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, antd

I have an app that will send an email to any email. I need to integrate the following

1.Image Upload - I look into the documentation of TinyMCE but I can't get to work the Image Upload. Can I use Dropzone plugin? If this will host in S3 will the Gmail can load the image?

2.File Attachment - How can I integrate the File Attachment?

Email Modal looks like this
[image: email]

Comment: hey can u share your code if you have solved this problem.